# How to change response code in an aspect?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my application I want controllers to return a subclass of my abstract class, where I'm putting common response sections:

```
public MyReturn getElement(){
 ...
```

and

```
public MyReturn extends MyAbstractResponse<String>{
       ...
}
```

and

```
public abstract MyAbstractResponse<T>{
      protected T data;

      @JsonIgnore
      private HttpStatus code = HttpStatus.OK;
}
```

Now, in case someone wants to change the default response code they can just update this class and there is no need to always wrap with a ResponseEntity which is useless 90% of time (usually you'll always want to return 200).

I need to somewhat intercep this response to edit the status code, so in my Controller aspect I do:

```
Object result = joinPoint.proceed(); //calls the controller
result.getCode(); //now how to retrieve the httpservlet response and add the code?
```

How can I obtain the response now?

edit:

I think I found my solution but I'm wondering if it is thread safe. It seems that I can simply inject the response and use its setCode:

```
public MyAspect {

   @Autowired
   private HttpServletResponse response; //I can use it!
}
```

but what happens if I have 2 threads at the same time? Would I risk to override the status codes?

Comment: why not using an mvc interceptor ? Seems more adequate here

Comment: I already have an aspect that would log request/response so I'd prefer to not add one more component